# Rotation about an axis in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, glut

So I have the following vectors:

```
up[]= {0,0,1}
focus[] = {-.5,0,-.25}
and v[] = {0,.5,0} (the cross product of focus X up)
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is rotate up and v around focus by an angle a, and then rotate up and focus around v by angle a for a flight simulator I'm working on.  We know both up and focus are orthogonal to v but not to one another.  Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: what OpenGl version are you using? Do you want an approach that uses the fixed function pipeline and glRotatef(), or a more general approach using matrices or quaternions to produce a model matrix?

Comment: Well I was using glulookat() with the parameters as glulookat(eye,eye+focus,up), where eye is the position of the plane as it moves through space, so I wanted to manipulate the above vectors such that when I update glulookat(), I'm either rolling side to side or pitching/yawing.  However, I would definitely be interested to see how this could be accomplished with glRotatef() as well.

Comment: I mean an easy way is just to do the inverse camera operation to your scene using glRotatef(), like if you want your camera to rotate about an axis by deg, rotate the entire scene around the same axis using -deg.

A more general solution is to produce the equivalent rotation matrix and multiply your vectors by this matrix.